# Django Allauth: Problem with Twitter Authentication

Tags: django, django-allauth

Allauth Github is working without any problem, however, Twitter is not.
When clicking on `https://0.0.0.0:9000/accounts/twitter/login/` nothing happens and yet there's no error. Everything is 200 ok.

I'm using SSL in dev environement using [django-sslserver](https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver).

```
settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
     ...

    'django.contrib.sites', # new
    'allauth', # new
    'allauth.account', # new
    'allauth.socialaccount', # new
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github', # new
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter', # new
    'sslserver',
]

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {'github': {}, 'twitter':{}}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

I use example.com in my hosts' file:

```
/etc/hosts

0.0.0.0 example.com
```

And in the Twitter app, I use these configurations:
[image: twiter conf]

This is the social app configuration:
[image]

And the site configuration:
[image]

Do you see any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback URL (can and) should be `https://127.0.0.1:9000/accounts/twitter/login/callback/`

This is how I solved this problem.